# CAKeyframeAnimation with different Durations value for animation in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

Here I am showing some frames (`.png`) with fixed duration 1 (total frame 20 so 1/20 = 0.05f) in CAKeyframeAnimation. It is running perfectly.

```
- (void)animateImages
{
    self.emoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 160, 50, 50)];
    self.emoImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:emoImageView];

    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_1.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_2.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_3.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_4.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_5.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_6.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_7.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_8.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_9.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_10.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_11.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_12.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_13.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_14.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_15.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_16.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_17.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_18.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_19.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_20.png"].CGImage, nil];      

    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
    //[anim setDuration:[[duration objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]];
    [anim setDuration:1];
    [anim setValues:values];
    [anim setKeyPath:@"contents"];
    [anim setCalculationMode:@"discrete"];
    [anim setRepeatCount: 90000];
    [self.emoImageView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
}
```

But now I want to show these frames with different Durations. I have an `NSArray` with different duration values:

```
NSArray *duration = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f], nil];
```

For that, I use a `for loop` for both of them, like this:

```
- (void)animateImages
{
    self.emoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 160, 50, 50)];
    self.emoImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:emoImageView];

    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_1.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_2.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_3.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_4.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_5.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_6.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_7.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_8.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_9.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_10.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_11.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_12.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_13.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_14.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_15.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_16.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_17.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_18.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_19.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_20.png"].CGImage, nil];

    NSArray *duration = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f],
                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f], nil];


    for (int i = 0; i < [duration count]; i++)
    {
        CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
        [anim setDuration:[[duration objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]];
        [anim setValues:@[[values objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [anim setKeyPath:@"contents"];
        [anim setCalculationMode:@"discrete"];
        [anim setRepeatCount: 90000];
        [self.emoImageView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
    }
}
```

But the Frames are not showing. How can I animate some frames with different Durations in `CAKeyframeAnimation`? 
Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing it right. Don't create multiple keyframe animations in a loop. Just like when you create an animation with all the same duration, create a single keyframe animation. However, to control the duration on a frame-by-frame basis, set the keyTimes property on your animation object to the array of durations that you created.

Note that the values for keyTimes are the relative start time for each frame in the animation. They must range from 0.0 to 1.0, and each subsequent value must be greater than the last:

```
#define steps 20

NSMutableArray *startTimes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: steps];
for (int i = 0; i< steps; i++)
{
  startTimes[i] = @(i* 1.0/2.0);
}
```

You should read the Xcode docs on CAKeyframeAnimation. They're actually quite informative.

BTW, any time you have code that does almost exactly the same thing over and over, it's worth thinking about making a loop. Like when you load your images:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: steps];
for (int i = 0; i< steps; i++)
{
  //The filenames start at 1, so use i+1 to create the filename.
  NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"smiley64_1_%d", i+1];
  images[i] = (id)[UIImage imageNamed: filename].CGImage;
}
```

Also note that you should usually not include the file extension in calls to imageNamed. If you don't, the system will load the image at the appropriate resolution (normal, @2x retina, or @3x retina.) I believe that including an explicit extension breaks that, although I'm not positive.

### Edit:

Read this bit from the docs:

> Each value in the array is a floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0
> that defines the time point (specified as a **fraction of the**
> **animation’s total duration**) at which to apply the corresponding
> keyframe value. Each successive value in the array must be greater
> than, or equal to, the previous value. Usually, the number of elements
> in the array should match the number of elements in the values
> property or the number of control points in the path property. If they
> do not, the timing of your animation might not be what you expect.

Comment: Good to see you sir. Thanks for commenting. What I understand is that, I have to arrange my keyTimes, like (0.0+1st duration)
then ((0.0+1st duration)+2nd duration) and it will goes on. But what I don't get is why it would be between 0.0 to 1.0? Is it because the Duration is counted 1 as a total?

Comment: Because they are relative start times. Think of them as percentages. The first frame starts 0% into the whole duration. By using values from 0 to 1, you can use the same startTime values and change the total duration of the animation without having to change your startTimes array.

Comment: That's great. Here is a problem I am facing, I set the keyTimes array according to my duration interchange. So it looks like keyTimes[0] = (0.0), keyTimes[1] = (0.04), keyTimes[2] = (0.8)......keyTimes[19] = (0.76), then set it like [anim setKeyTimes:keyTimes]; But the animation playing so fast. but if I set the duration according to my total keyFrams like [anim setDuration:0.76]; it animated perfectly.

Comment: You must set a duration for the animation, and then your key times values control the fraction of the total animation time where each step begins. **The keyTimes values are not expressed in seconds.** They are a fraction of the total duration, whatever that is.

Comment: I really grateful that you continue support on my question. Thanks a lot for that. Let me tell you something. Every time I will get two arrays here by JSON parsing. These data are not fixed and could be added more from server. [Yet just one set (.png array and time interval array), but there will be more set]". Image Array" store the frames. Time Interval between frames hold another array. Which I call here as "duration Array".

Comment: I don't have any "KeyTimes" value. So, I have to make "KeyTimes" value from the time interval values. What you said earlier I understand. And from that I do a little experiment, and after running different time interval animation (with various type of time interval not only like 0.04), it seems to me working perfectly. I can't put those code here in comment section. Please see in the answer section.

Comment: I can't tell what code you edited in your original question. As a matter of form, you should leave your original question intact, and add an **EDIT** at the end, showing the updates. That way people reading the question and the answers and comments understand the discussion and can learn from it. Plus, it lets the people trying to help you see what you changed. Your code above is still creating multiple CAKeyframeAnimation objects, which is wrong.

Comment: I didn't **Edit** my original question post. It is still intact as it was. I just gave an answer in my answer section. Below the original question post. I absolutely agree with you. It's all about sharing knowledge with people. That's why I have posted an answer above, which seems to me is working. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04",
                             @"0.04", nil];


    [self animateImages];
}

- (void)animateImages
{
    self.emoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 160, 50, 50)];
    self.emoImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:emoImageView];


    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_1.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_2.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_3.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_4.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_5.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_6.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_7.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_8.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_9.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_10.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_11.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_12.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_13.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_14.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_15.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_16.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_17.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_18.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_19.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_20.png"].CGImage, nil];


    // The total duration of my animation
    float Duration = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [durationArray count]; i++)
    {
        Duration = Duration + [[durationArray objectAtIndex: i] floatValue];
    }

    NSMutableArray *keyTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    float keyTimesRow = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [durationArray count]; i++)
    {
        keyTimesRow = keyTimesRow + ([[durationArray objectAtIndex: i] floatValue]/Duration);
        NSNumber *k = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:keyTimesRow];
        //keyTimes[0] = @(0.0);
        [keyTimes addObject:k];
    }


    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
    [anim setDuration:Duration];
    [anim setKeyTimes:keyTimes];
    [anim setValues:values];
    [anim setKeyPath:@"contents"];
    [anim setRepeatCount: -1];
    [self.emoImageView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
}
```

Here I just calculate the total duration of my Animation. So that latter I can set it with my Animation instance.

```
// The total duration of my animation
        float Duration = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [durationArray count]; i++)
        {
            Duration = Duration + [[durationArray objectAtIndex: i] floatValue];
        }
```

Here I am creating KeyTimes array from the time interval of each frames. And create the keyTimes array.

```
NSMutableArray *keyTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        float keyTimesRow = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [durationArray count]; i++)
        {
            keyTimesRow = keyTimesRow + ([[durationArray objectAtIndex: i] floatValue]/Duration);
            NSNumber *k = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:keyTimesRow];
            //keyTimes[0] = @(0.0);
            [keyTimes addObject:k];
        }
```

And finally set all these in animation instance.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
        [anim setDuration:Duration];
        [anim setKeyTimes:keyTimes];
        [anim setValues:values];
        [anim setKeyPath:@"contents"];
        [anim setRepeatCount: -1];
        [self.emoImageView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```